# Paste corresponding cell value using Nested If

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Following is my data structure

```
     A      |  B   |           C          |          D            |           E            
Company Name| Year | First Trading (Year) | Suspended From (Year) | Suspended Till (Year)

|        F          |
| Year of Delisting |
```

I need to have corresponding values of A in `column G`, where if the year (`column B`) matches First Trading (`Column C`) and if it is true then any value of B would not be between `column D and E`. Moreover, if values of B are greater than values of F then it would return 0 in `column G`.

I had used `If (B2>=C2,if(B2<F2,if(and(b2<d2,b2>e2),a2),0),0),0)` in cell `G2` but still no help?

It would be great help to me if anybody can rectify my statement or tell me a way to do it.

Many Thanks,

Sagnik

Comment: sorry the if statement:
"If(B2>=C2,if(b2<f2,if(and(b2<d2,b2>e2)a2,0),0),0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following **IF statement**:

```
=IF(AND(B2=C2,OR(B2<D2,B2>E2)),IF(B2>F2,0,A2),0)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The issue being company XYZ have multiple entry where the year (Column B) changes and Column C, D, E and F are the same. I need to find out  companies whose corresponding year are the greater than or equal to first trading year and also such that it does not lie within the range specified between D and E. Also, if B2 is equal to F2 then it must return 0.

Comment: Your comment conflicts with to your questions (`Moreover, if values of B are greater than values of F then it would return 0 in column G` vs. `Also, if B2 is equal to F2 then it must return 0`). Can you please update your question with the correct requirements and also include sample date. Based on your instructions I was not aware the each company had multiple entries.